# swift refresh tab bar controller to show badge on tab bar item

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi I would like to by able to call a function from any controller

that in turn calls

viewDidAppear in my tabBarController.

I want this as when someone moves to any screen I would like check the database to see if there are any unread messages and then update the badge on the message tab bar item accordingly.

below is the viewDidAppear function

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("viewDidAppear called in custom tab bar controller")

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {

            guard let dictionary = document.data() else { return }
            guard let unReadMessage = dictionary["unReadMessage"] as? Int else {

                 self.tabBar.items![3].badgeValue = nil
                return }

            if unReadMessage == 1 {
                print("unReadMessage value was 1! xxxxx")

                self.tabBar.items![3].badgeValue = ""
            } else {
                self.tabBar.items![3].badgeValue = nil
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you print `unReadMessage` under the `guard let`? Do you get any expected result from it?

Comment: that's not the issue ,  the issue is calling the function from another controller

Comment: I understand that, but still if the `unReadMessage` is empty, you will never see if the badge is set or not.

Comment: ok thanks , I will add code in there for save measure,

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set the tabBar item you can do it by this

```
if let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items{
   let tabItem = tabItems[3]
   tabItem.badgeValue = "new"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I assume this can be called from any controller ? , i need to leave the computer for a while but i will test it later.

Comment: @benpalmer Hmm, I can't promise you to a 100%. I guess it's required from a ViewController INSIDE the TabBarController. But test it out and we will figure out another way if not.